# merging my register page with fancybox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox

Im trying to put my "register.php" into fancybox, however I cant make it connect there.

To call up fancybox I use this:

```
<body>
    <a href="#test" class="fancybox">Open</a>
    <div id="test" style="display:none;width:400px; height:600px;" 
    **Content here**
    <!--Javascript for fancybox--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {      
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();  
        });
    </script>
```

My register form is like this:

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Registration Form</title>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Registration form to be output if the POST variables are not
        set or if the registration script caused an error. -->
        <h1>Register with us</h1>
        <?php
        if (!empty($error_msg)) {
            echo $error_msg;
        }
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li>Usernames may contain only digits, upper and lower case letters and underscores</li>
            <li>Emails must have a valid email format</li>
            <li>Passwords must be at least 6 characters long</li>
            <li>Passwords must contain
                <ul>
                    <li>At least one upper case letter (A..Z)</li>
                    <li>At least one lower case letter (a..z)</li>
                    <li>At least one number (0..9)</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Your password and confirmation must match exactly</li>
        </ul>
        <form method="post" name="registration_form" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
            Username: <input type='text' name='username' id='username' /><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
            Password: <input type="password"
                             name="password" 
                             id="password"/><br>
            Confirm password: <input type="password" 
                                     name="confirmpwd" 
                                     id="confirmpwd" /><br>
            <input type="button" 
                   value="Register" 
                   onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                                   this.form.username,
                                   this.form.email,
                                   this.form.password,
                                   this.form.confirmpwd);" /> 
        </form>
        <p>Return to the <a href="index.php">login page</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Im using the latest version of fancybox and I havent done much with the js files. Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't closed your div opening tag.

Comment: closing them wont make me connect

Comment: are you loading the contents of register.php inside `<div id="test">`?

Comment: Good point, will look into it:)